# Fibers of Morphisms between Specs

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question about following reducing step in analysing fibers $e^{-1} (p)$ 
for $p \in Spec(R)$ of $f:Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$.
There is given following diagramm it's commutativity should justify the reducing the
exploration of fibers of $Spec(R)$ to those of a $Spec(K)$ for a field K:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spec(A_p / pA_p) @>{a}  >> Spec(A_p) @>{b}  >> Spec(A) \\
@VVcV  @VVdV  @VVeV \\
Spec(R_p / pR_p) @>{f}>>Spec(R_p) @>{g}>> Spec(R);
\end{CD}
$$

Setting: $\phi: R \to A$ a ringhomom, $f = Spec(\phi)$ the induced morphism on Specs. 
$A_p, R_p$ are localisations of A and R in multiplicative system $ S = R \backslash p $. I know that 
$R_p$ is local with maximal ideal $p R_p$, so $R_p/pR_p$ is a field. Futhermore b and g
are injective  morphisms because for every multiplicative system S we have the identification $Spec(RS^{-1}) \cong \{p \in Spec(R) | p \cup S = \emptyset \}$.

My question is why thats enought to explore the fibers of 
$c: Spec(A_p / pA_p) \to Spec(R_p / pR_p)$ instead of those of $e$ or in other words:
how to see that there exist a bijection between $e^{-1}(p)$,  $d^{-1}(p R_p)$ (between $d^{-1}(p R_p)$ and $c^{-1}(0)$ it's clear). Because by injectivity of $b$ I only see that the fibers $e^{-1} (p)$ are only "included" in $d^{-1}(p R_p)$ but don't see
a 1-1 correspondence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $q\in \operatorname{Spec}(A_p)$ and $d(q)=pR_p$.  Then $p=g(pR_p)=g(d(q))=e(b(q))$.  That is, $b(q)\in e^{-1}(p)$.  Thus identifying $\operatorname{Spec}(A_p)$ with its image under $b$, $d^{-1}(pR_p)\subseteq e^{-1}(p)$.

You claim to already understand the reverse inclusion, but that is the harder one.  You first need to check that every $r\in e^{-1}(p)$ is in the image of $b$ at all.  To check this, note that $e(r)=p$ means $p=\phi^{-1}(r)$ so $r$ is disjoint from the set $\phi(S)$, which is exactly the condition that characterizes the image of $b$.  You can then write $r=b(q)$ and reverse the steps above: if $e(b(q))=p$ then $g(d(q))=g(pR_p)$, so $d(q)=pR_p$ since $g$ is injective.  Thus every element of $e^{-1}(p)$ is the image of an element of $d^{-1}(pR_p)$ under $b$.